# Should I need to update data manually after NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification

Tags: core-data, synchronization, icloud

I have a problem. I'm writing an app that using core data and syncing it through iCloud. Should I need to update data in context after receiving changes. Can I discard received changes?

Answer (score 2):

When you get `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`, the incoming changes have already been received and saved to your persistent store file. What you do next is up to you.

> Should I need to update data in context after receiving changes

If you want your users to see the new changes, then yes. You can do this with `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:`.

> Can I discard received changes?

When you get the notification, the changes are already received and saved. You could save different values if you want. You don't get to tell iCloud whether or not to commit the changes though-- they're already there.

Comment: Tom is that right, I was under the impression that you could iterate over the objects listed in the notification and delete (or change) them prior to calling mergeChanges.  So for example if there are duplicates you could remove them prior to the merge such that duplicates would never show in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

What Tom says is true. The changes are already imported into the persistent store file, but they are not merged into the actual PersistentContext, this is what mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification does.